# Multiple Content-type in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-mvc, mime-types

Can we have multiple content-type in Spring MVC request header?
I'm passing:

```
{Content-type = application/json, text/plain}
```

through Postman to my API. Currently, I'm getting `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Invalid mime type ....`

I wanted to know, is there something with my input values, or we can't have multiple content-type in our header.

```
Controller:
```

> @RequestMapping(value = "/addressees", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = GET)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, spring mvc request mapping supports multiple consumes MIME type , sample looks like

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = PUT, 
                consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}, 
                produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public SomeObject updateSomeObject(SomeObject acct) {
    return doStuff(acct);
}
```

Add consumes part in requestmapping like - **consumes = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}**

For know more, refer this link -

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html

Answer (score 2):

Your request header can have one content-type per request. You specify to the server what type of data are actually being sent.

Your server/API endpoint can support multiple.

So if your request specifies both application/json and text/plain at the same time, I believe it is a problem with your request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `RequestMapping.consumes` accepts an array of Mime types

`String[] consumes() default {};`

Note that you have to use `consumes` to define the incoming MIME types. `produces` is for the outgoing type.